# Check date field between 2 other date fields

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to check if a date is between two other dates. But it doesn't seems to work.

I've created a simple case statement:

```
CASE
WHEN date1 BETWEEN date2 AND date3
THEN 'Yes'
ELSE 'No'
END
```

But it gives me no all the time, and yes i'm sure there are some dates between date2 and date3. Am i missing something?

Comment: What type are your date columns?

Comment: All columns are date types

Comment: Read Aaron Bertrand's [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to CASE is IIF but you still do the same comparison

```
 IIF(date1 between date2 AND date3, 'Yes', 'No')
```

or without BETWEEN

```
IIF(date1 >= date2 AND date1 <= date3, 'Yes', 'No')
```

Comment: The IIF(date1 >= .....) worked, thanks a lot. But what is the difference on between? for me it looks like the same

Comment: You can consider IIF to be a short version of CASE suitable when there is only one WHEN.

Comment: Me to,great answer

Comment: I cannot fathom how this answer would work when the OP's code does not work.

Answer (score 3):

I would prefer >= and <= than the between

```
CASE
WHEN date1>=date2 AND date1<=date3
THEN 'Yes'
ELSE 'No'
END
```

Comment: For a value between two values you did't need = comparison. Greater then value 2 and less then value 3 is enough.

Comment: Nice and explicit and easier to comprehend instead of `BETWEEN`.

Answer (score 1):

Good day,

There is no problem in using the format which you provided. Unfortunately, without the ability to read-minds and since you did not provided any sample data and requested result, we have no idea why the result of `"no all the time"` does not fit you. The only thing you need to understand what "BETWEEN" means

Here is full example which works well, using the format you provided

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T
GO
CREATE TABLE T(
    id int,
    DT1 DATE,
    DT2 DATE,
    DT3 DATE
)

INSERT T(id, DT1, DT2, DT3) values 
(1,'2005-01-01','2001-01-01','2019-01-01'),
(2,'2000-01-01','2001-01-01','2019-01-01'),
(3,'2019-01-01','2019-01-01','2019-01-01')
GO

SELECT * FROM T
GO

SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN DT1 BETWEEN DT2 AND DT3
        THEN 'Yes'
        ELSE 'No'
    END 
FROM T
```

You can notice that the first row has '2005-01-01' is bigger than '2001-01-01' and smaller than '2019-01-01' = therefore it fits and the result is "yes"

The second row has '2000-01-01' which is smaller than '2001-01-01' = therefore it NOT fits and the result is "no"

Third row has '2019-01-01' which is bigger than '2001-01-01' and same value as '2019-01-01' = therefore it fits and the result is "yes"